# search folder and check file in

Tags: search, directory, defined

I need help for this:

Check a file exist, in a predefined folder ..

My example:

```
DIM fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists("file1.exe")) Then
If (fso.FileExists("secondfile.exe)) Then
MsgBox "file esxist",  0+16, "---"
WScript.Quit()
Else
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("a file")
WScript.Sleep(1000)
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End If
Else
MsgBox "Not founded file1.exe"
WScript.Quit()
End If
```

If founded file1.exe,then search a second file .. if this too founded,then send a message "file exist" if not founded, then run a program and exit wscript.

What i need?
the files in the folder, locate the script that we provide before launch!

For example, I'll give it to C: \ folder trololo locate the file, it looks for and if you have to perform the operations.

How can I solve for that search before ask which folder to locate the file? There is no way I could figure out: (

Sorry for bad english :/